# A category is locally finitely presented if the relative purity and purity coincide

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a locally finitely presented additive category, $X$ an additive subcategory.
A sequence $0\rightarrow A_1\rightarrow A_2\rightarrow A_3\rightarrow 0$ in $A$ is pure exact
if it is $\operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{fp}\!A,-)$-exact.
A sequence $0\rightarrow X_1\rightarrow X_2\rightarrow X_3\rightarrow 0$ in $X$ is $X$-pure exact if it is $\operatorname{Hom}(X\cap \operatorname{fp}\!A,-)$-exact.
If these two concepts coincide in $X$, can we infer that any object in $X$ can be written as direct limit of objects in $X\cap \operatorname{fp}\!A$?

Comment: I'm confused, because the definition of pure-exact given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_submodule) seems to be _stronger_ than exactness, whereas your notion seems to be _weaker_ than exactness. Is there somewhere I can read about your notion of pure exactness? What are some examples of sequences that are pure-exact but not exact? And what are some examples of the sorts of $X$ that you have in mind?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! A kind of artin algebra called virtually Gorenstein algebra (see A.Beligiannis's paper on J. Algebra) will give such an example, just taking $A$ to be the category of modules, $X$ to be the category of Gorenstein projective modules. What I am concerned is whether or not the converse is also true.